# Как узнать обьекты ссылающиеся на конкретный обьект через ForeignKey?

Tags: python, django-orm, django

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=30)       
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True)
```

как мне можно узнать всех детей конкретного обьекта(статьи)?

Answer (score 3):

используй атрибут related_name. Например:

```
...
parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, related_name="children")
```

А потом получай их как article.children.all()

Answer (score 1):

```
article.article_set
```